# How to change size of Polygon Collider 2D in uniform manner or evenly in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

When editing polygon collider 2D, we have a option to click and drag to change each edge.

Is there any method or hotkey that enable to enlarge or small whole polygon collider 2D in one click and drag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you resize your `gameObject(spriterenderer)` collider will automatically resize according to it. If you want to play only with collider then make an empty `child` of object paste component (i.e. `polygon collider`) as new in that `child` and remove from `parent`.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to resize something uniform? I'm a little confused by your question and description. From what i know, unity allows you to resize 2D sprites on uniform x and y proportions just but clicking Shift while dragging the object.

If that's not what you wanted, let me know.